# how to make array of objects from array based on some condtion in javascript

Tags: javascript

i have an array like `let x = [1,5,2,6,7,9]`

but i want to make this as array of objects like below code map or JSON

```
   let y = [
             { st:1,ed:2}, 
             {st:5,ed:7},
             {st:9,ed:9}
             ]
```

based on the continuity of the digits, any help or suggestion required

Comment: what happens to `6`? why the random order?

Comment: @Nina Scholz no need of 6 it just {st:5,ed:7} interview question, needed only start and end

Comment: This makes absolutely no sense to me ... unless I'm missing some piece of the puzzle.

Comment: what does it mean **based on the continuity of the digits**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could sort the array and reduce the array by inserting a new object or updat the end vlaue, depending on the first item or if the last value is not in short range.

> In parts:
>
> ```
> .sort((a, b) => a - b)
> ```
>
> sorts the array by taking the delta of twor elements and returns the needed value for using [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some). The array fter sorting looks like
>
> ```
> [1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 9]
> ```
>
> The more complex part is to use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) which returns the final array of objects.
>
> ```
> .reduce((accumulator, value, index) => {
>     if (!index || accumulator[accumulator.length - 1].end + 1 < value) {
>         accumulator.push({ start: value, end: value });
>     } else {
>         accumulator[accumulator.length - 1].end = value;
>     }
>     return accumulator;
> }, []);
> ```
>
> At the beginning, where `index` is zero, the first object is pushed to the `accumulator`.
>
> Then it takes the next value form the array and while `!1` is not true, the second part of the check
>
> ```
> accumulator[accumulator.length - 1].end + 1 < value
> ```
>
> is evaluated and returns `false`, so the else part updates the `end` property.
>
> Finally the accumulator is returned and contains the wanted result.

```js
var array = [1, 5, 2, 6, 7, 9],
    result = array
        .sort((a, b) => a - b)
        .reduce((accumulator, value, index) => {
            if (!index || accumulator[accumulator.length - 1].end + 1 < value) {
                accumulator.push({ start: value, end: value });
            } else {
                accumulator[accumulator.length - 1].end = value;
            }
            return accumulator;
        }, []);
 
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: oh my undertaker it complex answer can you add more info at least i will try to understad

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.sort`, `Array.filter` and `Array.flatMap` as well like below

- `sort` will sort the array in increasing order and will result in - `[1,2,5,6,7,9]`
- `filter` will then filter those results whose value is continuous when checked with left and right values and so it will result in - `[1,2,5,7,9]` as only `6` is value which has just difference of value 1 when compared with left and right values
- `flatMap` will then loop through the above result and prepare your desired output

```js
let x = [1,5,2,6,7,9]

let res = x.sort()
           .filter((d, i, t) => !(d == t[i-1] + 1 && d == t[i+1] - 1))
           .flatMap((d, i, t) => i%2 == 0 ? [{ st: d, en: t[i+1] || d }] : [])

console.log(res)
```